# How to quickly create a new directory without using dired-mode?

Tags: commands, directories

Whenever I've to create a  new directory in emacs, I enter dired mode, press "+" and enter the new directory name which creates the new directory. 
Is there a way I can avoid using dired-mode and create a new directory in the current path of the active buffer like creating a new file using `C-x C-f` command ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `M-x make-directory DIRNAME RET`.  The default path is the path to the current buffer folder.

You could bind it to key (like `C-x C-f`) with `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'make-directory)`.

You could create buffer in nonexist path with `C-x C-f non/exist/path/file.name RET` and then create nececcary folders with `M-x make-directory RET RET`.

Comment: `M-x mkdir` works too.

Comment: `mkdir` is an alias for `make-directory`.